# Select first item of Autocomplete Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete, cypress, react-hook-form

I have a react hook forms that contains Autocomplete material UI controls.

```
    <Controller
      as={
        <Autocomplete
          data-cy="profileCountry"
          options={countries}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              label="* Country"
              placeholder="Select a Country"

              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true
              }}
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
        />
      }
      rules={{ required: true }}
      onChange={([, data]) => data}
      defaultValue={{ id: 0, name: "" }}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
      name="country"
      id="country"
      control={control}
    />
```

I want to run a cypress test case to fill up the form and submit. How can I select like the first option in this component using cypress.

Currently I just tried my luck like the following.

```
cy.get("[data-cy=profileCountry]").select("Germany");
```

Comment: Could make a codesanbox and so it's easier to repro?

Answer (score 11):

I used this and it works:

```
 cy.get('.MuiAutocomplete-popper li[data-option-index="0"]').click();
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. To select the wanted option regardless of their original position in the list, I used this code: `cy.get("#state").type("Roma").get('li[data-option-index="0"]').click();`

... where `<Autocomplete id="state" ... />`

Answer (score 6):

Add a custom command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getDropdownOptions', () => {
  return cy.get('.MuiAutocomplete-popper [role="listbox"] [role="option"]', {
    timeout: 10000,
  });
});
```

Then you can simply...

```
cy.getDropdownOptions().contains('Germany').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First click on the autocomplete to make the options popup

```
cy.get('[data-testing=\'currency-picker\']').click();
```

And then find the specific option you want to choose, and click on it.

```
cy.contains('Indian Rupee').click();
```

Just like a human would do. What is so confusing about it

Answer (score -1):

```
  cy.get("#combo-box").click();
        cy.get("li[data-option-index="0"]").contains("ntest_user").then((option)=> 
         {
            option[0].click();
        })
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a `.then()` callback in this code.

Answer (score -1):

You need the follwing:

```
cy.wait(2000) // waiting for ajax to complete (till the request is resolved)
cy.get('#The MUI ID').click({force:true}).focused().type('Germany');
cy.contains('Germany').click({force:true});
```

Answer (score -2):

Assuming we give an id to the autocomplete such as

```
              id="pool-leg-autoComplete"
              freeSolo
              options={legOptions.map((option) => option.title)}
              onChange={updateNewLegItemText}
              renderInput={(params: any) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Add a leg to the pool"
                  margin="normal"
                  autoFocus
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={newLegItemText}                 
                />
```

`cy.get('#pool-leg-autoComplete-option-0').click();`

Where the index of the item is 0 in this case.